# weird es6 extends classes

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I tried to craft a text slider, but I got weird result:

```
TypeError: HomeHeaderSlider.init is not a function
```

I am still learning es6 javascript.

Here are my classes:

```js
        import S from "skylake"

        class HomeHeaderSlider {

            init(e, t) {

            function i() {
                o.dataset.headerslider = h,
                t()
            }

            let o = S.Geb.id("h-header"),
                // some other variables

            "h-header-arrow-btn-left" === e.target.id ? (h = 0 === c ? 5 : c - 1, d = -1) : (h = c < 5 ? c + 1 : 0, d = 1)
            // some content

            }

        }
```

And here is the class extends...

```
        class HomeController extends HomeHeaderSlider {

            constructor(e) {
                super();
                S.BindMaker(this, ["addListeners", "getHomeHeaderSlider"]),
                this.RO = new S.RO({
                throttle: {
                    delay: 100,
                    atEnd: !0
                }
                })
            }
            init(e) {
                let t = this                    
                this.addListeners()
            }
            addListeners() {
                this.listeners("add")
            }
            listeners(e) {
                "add" === e ? this.RO.on() : this.RO.off(),
                S.Listen(".h-header-arrow-btn", e, "click", this.getHomeHeaderSlider)
            }
            getHomeHeaderSlider(e) {
                this.listeners("remove"),
                HomeHeaderSlider.init(e, this.addListeners)
            }
            destroy(e, t) {
                this.listeners("remove")
            }

        }

        console.log(h)
        // export default HomeHeaderSlider

        const slidctrl = new HomeController()
        slidctrl.init()
        export default HomeController
```

It sems the code doesn't call the `HomeHeaderSlider.init` function.

My question is how can I call it?

Comment: In JavaScript class you need to bind all the methods to `this` in the constructor: `this.init = this.init.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HomeHeaderSlider` is your class.  There is no such function `HomeHeaderSlider.init()` on the class.  The `.init()` method is on `HomeHeaderSlider.prototoype.init` or on an object instance of `HomeHeaderSlider`.

In this method:

```
        getHomeHeaderSlider(e) {
            this.listeners("remove"),
            HomeHeaderSlider.init(e, this.addListeners)
        }
```

it isn't entirely clear what you're trying to do there.  If you want to call the base class version of `.init()` rather than your `HomeController` version of it, then you can use `super.init()` as in:

```
        getHomeHeaderSlider(e) {
            this.listeners("remove"),
            super.init(e, this.addListeners)
        }
```

---

It also looks like you may have an issue with the binding of `this` in this line:

```
 S.Listen(".h-header-arrow-btn", e, "click", this.getHomeHeaderSlider)
```

where you need to change that to this:

```
S.Listen(".h-header-arrow-btn", e, "click", this.getHomeHeaderSlider.bind(this))
```

so that your `getHomeHeaderSlider()` method will have the proper value of `this` when it is called.  When you pass `this.getHomeHeaderSlider` to a function, it looks on `this`, gets the reference to the `getHomeHeaderSlider` method and passes only the reference to that method.  When the click handler later calls your method, there's no connection at all to the right object so the value of `this` is lost.  Using `.bind()` the way I showed allows you to make sure the proper value of `this` stays connected to the method call.  This is needed when passing a reference to a method of an object that is going to get called by some other agent that doesn't know anything about your object.

Comment: thank you, i understood and realized my mistake. it works now, i just applied **super.init(e, this.addListeners)** as you said.